# Can I maintain Database access results?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm setting up a django server, and want to maintain database access results.
For example, I'm using infinite scroll on front end. When I reached the end, FE request data from Django. Then I want to keep the results in Django. Is it possible?

Backend is django server and frontend is react-native.
I considered using offset and seek method, but that wasn't what I wanted.

I want to database access only once and maintain that results in Django.
Likes React State

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you perhaps looking for [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)?

Comment: I am concidering about fetch call optimization plz help me